# Correct wording/spelling for our company's new slogan

Tags: grammar, orthography, slogan

I work for a small company (located in Italy) which makes websites and sells/repairs computers.
Right now we are in the process of creating a new logo and updating our slogan / corporate design.

My colleagues / boss came up with the following idea for a slogan: (none of us are native english speakers)

[COMPANY NAME]

***links the digital world***

Now - I'm really not sure if "links the digital world" is correct or does even make sense at all. I think the idea was that we - as a company - link our clients to the digital world, but "linking you to the digital world" was apparently too long and/or clumsy. In my opinion, it should as least be "links the digital world TO something" or "linking the digital world".

I need your assistance as native english speakers: How does this slogan sound to you

Thanks!

Comment: American here... You are correct, "Linking" is better - if only because it is more obviously a verb in that form.

Comment: In terms of how it "sounds", a lot depends on the specific company name, as well as the nationality of the person reading the slogan.

Comment: I agree that ***linking*** *the digital world* sounds better. But it also depends on if you're supposed to read the slogan immediately after reading the company name. *Company Name links the digital world* is just fine, whereas *Company Name linking the digital world* is odd.

Comment: Thanks everyone for providing some feedback. It is much appreciated. I guess in the end it comes down to a matter of taste. As @JasonBassford pointed out, if you read the slogan immediately after the company name, it indeed makes some sense: **Company Name links the digital world**

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I misunderstood the question and thought the **[company name]** designation was asking for a suggestion for a new name in addition to the best wording for a "**logo**".

Moving on to the actual choices for a new "**logo**" then. I agree that "**Linking the digital world**" does sound better. But, you could also consider simply adding the preposition "**to**" to your colleagues' suggestion thus making it "**Links to the digital world**". Lastly, here is a third suggestion if smaller is better. I will offer the easy phrase - "**The digital link**"

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Our company's name is already defined, we cannot change that. We were just looking for some kind of slogan to put under the already existing logo.